I am trying to do a calculation using Measure in Power Bi using TRUE or False
I am trying to carry out a calculation in Power bi using measure where if column A has been filled and column B is also filled (regardless of the value) it means that evaluation has been carried out.
And in the case either columns is not filled within the table it means the evaluation for that particular item has not been completed.
Finally, the goal is to compare the filled columns against the unfilled columns (the unfilled columns will be considered as needing additional evaluation)

In this table i have a field with documentation incomplete. My goal is to have a measure that compares the columns with the various parameters and the fields with either one or more of the values missing, it counts as incomplete evaluation

Any data ? formula? logic ?

Calculated column?
NeedsMoreWork = IF(ISBLANK('table'[ColA]) || ISBLANK('table'[ColB]), "Needs Work", "Okay")
?
